# No module named virtualenvwrapper and fail to run the initialization hooks

Tags: python, macos, virtualenvwrapper

I am using macOS 10.13.3, and if I open the terminal, it will automatically print the following message:

```
If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, 
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization 
hooks.
```

I tried the command

```
/usr/local/bin/pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

and it returns

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in 
./.venvburrito/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper in 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone in 
./.venvburrito/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: stevedore in 
./.venvburrito/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr>=1.6 in 
./.venvburrito/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from stevedore-
>virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in 
./.venvburrito/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from stevedore-
>virtualenvwrapper)
```

and if I tried

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

then I got this:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-
packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): 
virtualenvwrapper in 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-
packages
Cleaning up...
```

How should I fix this problem and make my terminal clean again? Thanks!